# Referencing a VBA button title within code

Tags: vba, excel

On my excel, I have about 200 buttons that link to displaying text boxes.
Is there any way of having just a single macro with something like:

ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("TextBox ***TEXT ON BUTTON CLICKED***")
and then have all of my buttons leading to the same macro, but returning different text boxes?

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Comment: post the code of one button

Comment: Basically you want `ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)` to get a reference to the clicked button - assuming it's a Form button, not ActiveX.

Answer (score 0):

some #Rory wrote, you can use `ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller)` where all buttons link to the same `Sub` and with select case you can play one code or another.
I can think of other solutions

```
Sub cmdAction()
    btn = ActiveSheet.Buttons(Application.Caller).Name
    Select Case btn
    Case xxxx
        Do
    Case Else
        Do
    End Select
End Sub
```